# Python, socket.error: [Errno 10049]

Tags: python, sockets

Working on a base for a simple chat client, and got the following error:

`socket.error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context`

The code is:

```
from socket import *
HOST = ''
PORT = 8000
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
i = True
while i is True:
    msg = raw_input("Write A MSG: ")
    s.send(msg)
    print "Awaiting reply"
    reply = s.recv(1024)
    print "Recived: ", repr(reply)

s.close()
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Which line is the error on? Also, possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162869/python-sockets-socketserver-connection

Comment: You can look here for [windows error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx) which seems to be the platform you are using. I suspect the problem you have is that your HOST variable is empty.

Comment: Please provide full traceback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Sockets/SocketServer Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162869/python-sockets-socketserver-connection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is:

```
...
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
```

And it is because `HOST = ""`. You may use `HOST = ""` when ***binding*** sockets. But when connecting, you should use `HOST = "localhost"` or `HOST = "someaddr.com"`.

Comment: HOST can also be the IP address of another machine on the network, right? e.g. '130.132.234.14'

Answer (score 2):

IP address (`HOST`) is not correct. If you want to access it from local computer you can use `'127.0.0.1'` or `'localhost'`. To access from anywhere use `'0.0.0.0'`.